# Scraping Ajax based Review Page with Scrapy

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

There. I am trying to scrape a website. Everything is working fine, the problem is that I cannot figure out how to scrape the ajax contents. The website I am scraping uses ajax content to get review pages using Post request. Here is what chrome dev tool say.

[Chrome Dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n20c.png)

I researched a lot but I cannot understand how to scrape ajax contents. I know about form data and post or get request but I cannot use them. Moreover, I don't know how to scrape the content I need. I guess it cannot be scraped using the XPath or selectors. Moreover, if you check the URL,in the review section there is read more button, is it possible to scrape it using the same strategy as for ajax content.

I was able to scrape the first page but I am stuck at next_page. this is how spider terminates, it gets the url for next page, requests but nothing happens.
[Output log of spider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC8QM.png)
Here is the code...

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from quo.items import QuoItem

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.daraz.pk/infinix-s2-pro-32gb-3gb-4g-lte-black-6619437.html', self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
         for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="reviews"]'):
          item=QuoItem()


          Rating=response.xpath('//*[@id="ratingReviews"]/section[3]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/@style').extract()
          if Rating:

              item['Rating']=Rating


          ReviewT=response.xpath('//*[@id="ratingReviews"]/section[3]/div[2]/article/div[2]/div[2]/text()').extract()
          if ReviewT:
              item['ReviewT']=ReviewT

          yield item

          next_page=response.xpath('(//ul[@class="osh-pagination -horizontal"]/li[@class="item"]/a[@title]/@href)[last()]').extract() #xpath for next button which contains the url.
          if next_page:

                       yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page[0]), callback=self.parse)
```

**Update requested in comments:**
I have tried to use it, but I guess I didn't use it good. It isn't doing anything. Here is the additon to the code

```
next_page=response.xpath('(//ul[@class="osh-pagination -horizontal"]/li[@class="item"]/a[@title]/@href)[last()]').e‌​xtract() 
if next_page: 
    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page[0]), callback=self.parse_jsonloads) 

def parse_jsonloads(self, response): 
    data=json.loads(response.body) 

    for item in data.get('reviews', []): 
        ReviewT=item.get('author') 

    yield json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

Comment: The "AJAX contents" is based on a second request, made using javascript by your web browser once the page has loaded, to the server to request data which the page then displays or acts upon. You simply need to find the URL to which the request is made (using, say, xpath if the url is in the original file), and then make a request to that url.

Comment: the next_page =response.xpath....does exactly the same. It gets the url and makes a request....yield scrapy.Request.. if you see the output log file that I have attached , you will see that it makes a request but nothing happens. Please point, if I am not understanding something here

Comment: It's hard to be sure since I can't test the code, but you seem to use the same callback (`self.parse`) for the json response as you do for the HTML response. The JSON response is just a JSON file, no HTML or XML to use XPATH on. Use a different callback for this request, and then parse the data using simply `yield json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())` - that should return what you want.

Comment: I have tried to use it, but I guess I didn't use it good. It isn't doing anything. Here is the additon to the code          next_page=response.xpath('(//ul[@class="osh-pagination -horizontal"]/li[@class="item"]/a[@title]/@href)[last()]').extract()
          if next_page:


                       yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page[0]), callback=self.parse_jsonloads)

    def parse_jsonloads(self, response):
     data=json.loads(response.body)
     for item in data.get('reviews', []):
      ReviewT=item.get('author')
      yield json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())