# Scrapy spider not saving html files

Tags: python, html, scrapy, web-crawler, output

I have a Scrapy spider that I've generated. The purpose of the spider is to return network data for the purposes of graphing the network as well as to return the html files for each page the spider reaches.  The spider is achieving the first goal but not the second. It results in a csv file with the tracking information but I cannot see that it is saving the html files.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc
from sitegraph.items import SitegraphItem


class CrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    custom_settings = {
    'DEPTH_LIMIT': '1',
    }
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = (
        'http://exampleurl.com',
    )

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        i = SitegraphItem()
        i['url'] = response.url
        # i['http_status'] = response.status
        llinks=[]
        for anchor in hxs.select('//a[@href]'):
            href=anchor.select('@href').extract()[0]
            if not href.lower().startswith("javascript"):
                llinks.append(urljoin_rfc(response.url,href))
        i['linkedurls'] = llinks
        return i

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

The traceback I receive is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
2019-07-23 14:16:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://externalurl.com/> (failed 3 times): TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
2019-07-23 14:16:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://externalurl.com/>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
2019-07-23 14:16:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-07-23 14:16:41 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (153 items) in: exampledomainlevel1.csv
```

Comment: use `print()` to check if `parse()` is executed. You can also use it to check values in variables. Display url to see what url makes problem and try to open it in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`parse` method:**

According to  [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) and [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620722/scrapy-crawlspider-crawls-nothing) it is not recommended to override `parse` method because crawlspider use it to implement it's logic.

If You need to override `parse` method and in the same time count with

[`Crawlspider.parse` original source code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1.6.0/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py#L42-L43) - You need to add it's original source to fix `parse` method:

```
def parse(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)
    return self._parse_response(response, self.parse_start_url, cb_kwargs={}, follow=True)
```

**csv feed:**
This log line:
`2019-07-23 14:16:41 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (153 items) in: exampledomainlevel1.csv` - means that csv `feedexporter` enabled (probably in `settings.py` project settings file.)

**UPDATE**

 I observed `Crawlspider` source code again.

 It looks like `parse` method called only once at the beginning and it don't cover all web responses.
If my theory correct - after adding this function to your spider class should save all html responses:

```
def _response_downloaded(self, response):
    filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.body)    
    rule = self._rules[response.meta['rule']]
    return self._parse_response(response, rule.callback, rule.cb_kwargs, rule.follow)
```

Comment: I just fixed the code as you recommended, however, this only seems to store the initial html page. I really need all the html files for each page the crawler hits. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: can you add/update your question with new changed code?