# While using scrapy, crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

As mentioned in the title, I'm using scrapy to extract data from particular pages (one website / one domain). Now I'd like to describe, what my code is about to do.

1. The scraper collects data from one of the most famous automotive ad portals in Poland - OTOMOTO (https://otomoto.pl). It extracts data from particular offer pages.
2. Firstly, the user inputs car make and then car model. Program checks if there is such make/brand (the list/array of brands is collected previously - using BeautifulSoup; then extracts car model list - also using BeautifulSoup). It works perfectly fine.

   In the final version of this code, I'll also collect some additional parameters/filters, like price range or production year range. But let's leave it for now. It's only about link creation.
3. If these conditions are met, then the URL with the list of offers is being created, under the abovementioned conditions (using brand and model) as follows: https://otomoto.pl/osobowe/BRAND/MODEL (for example: https://otomoto.pl/osobowe/opel/corsa). This is the starting point for collecting the URLs of particular offers which are inside this link. I only collect results from the first page, wishing not to exploit the server much. That's why the *rules* for crawling are not necessary to implement in this case.
4. Then, the BeautifulSoup finds the URLs that meet the pattern of offer page: https://otomoto.pl/oferta/BRAND-MODEL-blah-blah-blah (for example: https://www.otomoto.pl/oferta/opel-corsa-darmowa-dostawa-serwis-aso-pdc-grzane-fotele-kiero-wielofunkcyjna-ID6DzPov.html#2034f5e3ae) - and then adds to array. This array variable is set as global.
5. At this point, I've encountered a problem. Because I want to acquire data from this particular pages (like mileage, color, engine power etc.) - all of these are required to provide to publish an advertisement, so there is no need to check if the variable appears on the page. Then these data should be assigned to a particular object (a "car") - and that's why I thought of Item extension of Scrapy. (I would like to save is as an json file or csv at the end - but let's leave it for now).

**In brief**: this spider is only about collecting data from defined websites (according to user's constraints) which are stored in dynamically created arrays.

What I've done:

- I created Item class which is described with the code below:

`class otoMotoCarObjects(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    offerID = scrapy.Field()
    addDate = scrapy.Field()
    offerType = scrapy.Field()
    brand = scrapy.Field()
    model = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    productionYear = scrapy.Field()
    mileage = scrapy.Field()
    fuelType = scrapy.Field()
    power = scrapy.Field()
    cubicCapacity = scrapy.Field()
    gearbox = scrapy.Field()
    driveType = scrapy.Field()
    color = scrapy.Field()
    countryImport = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    state = scrapy.Field()`

- I imported necessary libraries:

`import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor`

- and I created the class which is responsible for crawling (scraping):

`class otoMotoCarScraper(CrawlSpider):
name = 'car'
allowed_domains = ['otomoto.pl']

def __init__(self, urls=[], *args, **kwargs):
    super(otoMotoCarScraper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = urls


def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_items)
    """
    return [scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            for url in self.start_urls]
    """

def parse_items(self, response):
    car = otoMotoCarObjects()
    car['url'] = response.url
    print(car['url'])
    car['offerID'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="ad-id"]//text()').extract_first()
    print(car['offerID'])
    car['addDate'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/span[3]/text()').extract()
    car['offerType'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['brand'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['model'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[4]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['price'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[1]/text()').extract()
    car['productionYear'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[5]/div/text()').extract()
    car['mileage'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[6]/div/text()').extract()
    car['fuelType'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[8]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['power'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[9]/div/text()').extract()
    car['cubicCapacity'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[7]/div/text()').extract()
    car['gearbox'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[10]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['driveType'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[1]/li[11]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['color'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[3]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['countryImport'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[8]/div/a/text()').extract()
    car['location'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/span[3]/text()').extract()
    car['state'] = response.xpath(
        '/html/body/div[3]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul[2]/li[10]/div/a/text()').extract()
    yield car

process = CrawlerProcess()`

It is worth mentioning that the code in the comment section (return scrapy.Request ...) is also not working, but I leave it for your information. (Maybe it's something good but improperly induced?) - I used it interchanchably with the *yield*

This scraper is launched in *main* function using this code: 
`scr.otoMotoCarScraper.process.crawl(scr.otoMotoCarScraper, urls=fun.offerUrls)`

 (where `scr` represents an imported file where this scraper exists and `fun` represents an imported file where are the functions defined and thus where the `offerUrls` table is stored).

The Scrapy log is as follows:

```
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
    {}
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 85e67e930e79de1f
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
    ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
     'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
     'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
    ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
    ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
     'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
    []
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
    2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
```

As you see, unfortunately I crawled/scraped 0 pages, as indicated in this line: 
`2021-02-13 14:39:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`

I tried to print `self.start_urls` - inside the `__init__` function and it shows properly as a table - I thought that it is something with passing the argument to the scraper but it seems to be pretty okay.

I also tried to change `return` - and converting it to `yield` but also nothing happened.

My thoughts:

- maybe it's something about not proper implementing XPath?

  - I tried the shorter and longer version of XPath (and printed them for trial) - as it can be deducted from the code - and still nothing happens
- maybe the issue is still about passing arguments?
- maybe the `otoMotoCarObject(scrapy.Item)` is not properly created?
- or maybe it's something about `response`?

Comment: it looks like it will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620722/scrapy-crawlspider-crawls-nothing