# How to scrape all website text from a page and every one-click subpage with Scrapy's crawlspider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrape a great number of websites for the text displayed to website users. I am using Scrapy to perform this task. So far, I have worked with the base spider and written code that

1. retrieves the websites' entire HTML code
2. parses the HTML code for text using BeautifulSoup's get_text()
3. saves separate files that contain the text information as well as the HTML code

The code does everything I want, except that it only scrapes the main page. My goal is to change the code so that it scrapes and saves the text of the main page, finds the links to all internal subsites that are one click away, and scrapes those sites for their text as well. Below is a simplified, minimal working example of the base spider.

```
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_list = [
        'https://www.apple.com',
        'https://www.macrumors.com',
        ]

class TXTSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mwe_spider'
    start_urls = url_list


    def parse(self, response):

        current_url = response.request.url
        filename = current_url.split(".")[-2]

        html = response.body

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        text = soup.get_text()

        with open(f'{filename}.txt', 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(text)

        with open(f'{filename}.html', 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(response.body)

        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

I tried adapting this code to achieve my goal. Specifically, I have found out that Scrapy's crawlspider class offers the required functionality. Based on what I have read, I made the following changes to my MWE:

1. changed the spider class from Scrapy's base spider to the crawlspider

by importing and implementing the CrawlSpider class (`class TXTSpider(CrawlSpider):`) as well as renaming the parse function to `def parse_item(self, response):` to avoid interference with the crawlspider ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620722/scrapy-crawlspider-crawls-nothing)). Lastly, I limited the spider to the websites I am interested in to avoid external websites: `allowed_domains = ['apple.com', 'macrumors.com']`).

2. added a rule to indicate that the spider should follow all website links

To my understanding, the following rule achieves this aim while avoiding links to images, etc.: `rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),)`

3. retained my original parse function (which was renamed to parse_item) since I still want to save the text and HTML information from the main page
4. added an additional parse function (parse_page) which is supposed to scrape the linked internal subsites for their text information (parsing for links once more is not necessary as I am only interested in sites one click away from the main page). parse_page is similar to the first parse function but appends the text information to the main page's text file to yield one merged file for a site's text. The code for writing a new HTML file remains unchanged in order to receive separate HTML files for the subpages.

The resulting code is pasted below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import tldextract


url_list = [
        'https://www.apple.com',
        'https://www.macrumors.com',
        ]

class TXTSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'mwe_crawlspider'
    allowed_domains = ['apple.com',
                       'macrumors.com'
                       ]

    start_urls = url_list

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )


    def parse_page(self, response):

        html = response.body
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        text = soup.get_text()

        domain = tldextract.extract(response.request.url)[1]
        path = urlparse(response.request.url)[2].replace("/", "")

        with open(f'{domain}.txt', 'a') as fp:
            fp.write(text)

        with open(f'{domain} {path}.html', 'wb') as fp:
            fp.write(response.body)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1:** The code was updated to re-define `filename` in the second parse function.

**EDIT 2:** Adding `DEPTH_LIMIT=1` to the settings.py file restricts the crawlspider to pages which are one click away from the provided url.

**EDIT 3:** Updated the code above which now performs all required tasks. Extracting the website's domain with `tldextract` ensures that the text information is appended to only one text file, even if the same site uses different URL formats for its subpages (e.g. [www.apple.com](http://www.apple.com) and tv.apple.com). `urlparse` is used to find the path information in order to save an individual HTML file for each subpage.

Comment: Have you worked through the Scrapy tutorial (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)? It is a very nice introduction and answers the questions that you have here

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @tomjn! I have worked through the tutorial and have also tried to utilize the crawlspider example to solve my challenge (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider-example). However, I am still struggling to deduce what I have to change from the provided examples.

Comment: Great! What actually isn't working with the new `CrawlSpider` (aside from parsing the start page)?

Comment: The ```CrawlSpider``` triggers a lot of activity in the terminal but does not actually write any files. According to the Scrapy stats, it requests over 400 pages (which indicates that the link extraction must have worked). However, there are over 300 error messages, many of which have the structure *ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.apple.com/subpage...> (referer: https://www.apple.com)* or *NameError: name 'filename' is not defined*. I cannot make sense of the first error type. The second could mean that my code construction with ```response.request.url``` is incorrect.

Comment: You should edit your question to include the error messages. The second one is because `filename` isn’t defined in `parse_page`

Comment: @tomjn I edited the code to define ```filename```in the second parse function. Thank you for the input, no more error messages! However, the crawlspider now accesses thousands of sites and saves them to disk; many of which are more than one click away from the main page (e.g.: https://tv.apple.com/us/person/rylan-lee/umc.cpc.z267d8ny41on13e3gpfexpl7)

Comment: Glad it works! See this setting: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=depth#depth-limit

Comment: You rock, @tomjn! Thank you! I added ```DEPTH_LIMIT=1``` to the settings.py file and it works just as intended. The challenge of creating one merged .txt file of the main page and all subpages while storing separate HTML files remains. I will look into this myself and report back – either with the working code or with another request for help ;)

Comment: @tomjn I updated the code which now works as intended. I know, saying "thank you" is not usually done on Stack Overflow, but who can be mad at a newbie like me? ;)