# Python Scrapy - scrapy.Request not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, request, httprequest

My scraper crawls 0 pages and I think the problem resides in the last line of code in the parse method:

```
def parse(self, response):
        all_companies = response.xpath('//header[@class = "card-header"]')

        for company in all_companies:
            company_url = company.xpath('./a[@class = "card-header-scorecard"]/@href').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=company_url, callback = self.parse_company)
```

I tested the retrieval of the company_url with the scraps shell and they are all returned correctly. The scraper accesses each of those urls and scrapes the items using the parse_company method.

Before using yield I was using the Rule feature and it worked perfectly together with parse_company so I know this method works, however I had to change my approach out of necessity.

```
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css=".card-header > a"), callback="parse_company")
)
```

Comment: Do you use `CrawlSpider`?

Comment: Yes I am using it

Comment: Then don't overwrite the `parse` method, name it something else.

Comment: I thought about overwriting the parse method cause it's called automatically. How would the code work if I named the parse method differently? I would the method get called

Comment: I solved the problem by using scrapy.Spider instead of CrawlSpider

Comment: Here's a very detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637316).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `CrawlSpider` and in latest versions of scrapy CrawlSpider's default callback is `_parse` instead of `parse`. If you want to override default callback then use `_parse` or you can use `scrapy.Spider` instead of `scrapy.CrawlSpider`

Comment: Thanks, using scrapy.Spider solved my problem